# How can I determine if there are public member functions in my code that should be private?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I am reviewing some code and in the doxygen docs I found a lot of member functions that are only used by the same class and it makes sense to me to change them to be private.

Is there a way to determine at compile time (maybe some tool like doxygen) that can list me all those functions?

Comment: This is all about *design* decisions. And so, you (the designer, programmer, whatever!) are the one who should be responsible for modifying and/or improving your current design. Tools may help you, but only to some extent.

Comment: I agree. In this case, we are reviewing a large legacy code base, and I'd like to identify these areas. It might not make sense to change all of the functions, but a tool that can help us goes a long way.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to determine at compile time (maybe some tool like doxygen) that can list me all those functions?

Sure ;-)
Change them to be private, and recompile.
If the build succeeds, then you're done.

If the build fails, then they "need" to be public/protected, and you can investigate why, and either fix the calling code or put them back.

I realize that this is not really what you asked for, but it does work.

I suspect that you could write something that does what you want based on clang.

Comment: Xcode will show you all the callers of a particular function. I'm pretty sure that Eclipse and Visual Studio have similar functionality.